# Why can't I access shared folders from host with 1 processor allocated, but I can with 4 processors?

Tags: vmware, shared-folders, logical-processor

I setup shared folders in the virtual machine settings for access to host files, but it didn't work no matter how many times I reinstalled `VMWare Tools`, changed the settings for the shared folders and restarted the machine afterwards. I always got the `unable to browse the network the network is not present` error message, although I had access both to the internet and to my host if I ran my IP address (VM is bridged).Then I realized the machine *had only 1 processor allocated and changed it to 4*... and IT WORKED! I had the shared files mapped in `explorer`. I would like to know why that is. Any ideas?

Comment: any possibility it's just a bug?

Comment: All my virtual machines only have 1 processor, and I have no issues. I would try using 1 processor with NAT, and see if the issue persists. Weird.

Comment: Had both NAT and bridged with 1 proc, didn't make any difference. I *did* solve the problem when I changed to 4 processors and it was ok, but I would like to know why it worked for 4 and not for 1.

Comment: This is probably just a problem with the timeout.

Comment: Should this be better answered on ServerFault perhaps? @GreatDane, could you add the version of VMware you're running here and perhaps the OSes on the VMs?

Comment: Also describe the network adapter(s) attached and in what mode.  Do you notice any change to these configurations when you allocate 4 CPU's?

Comment: Does it happen again when you change it back to one cpu?

Answer (score 2):

I think that is an issue specific to your hardware as it not behaving as expected. It is an issue of timing out of scheduling of an event. Shared services seeks time to look up the network discovery and find the content that is shared, decide the protocol for the communication, and then gets content if everything is okay. So it may appear that the CPU times out before this process is completed.

I hope it helps.